# Convergence of gradient descent method with one parameter

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, machine-learning, linear-regression, mean-square-error

We want to minimize the mean square error in a regression model that uses just one paremeter $w_0$. For convinience we take the mean square error to be $MSE(w_0) = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_n - w_0)^2$ so that gradient descent method takes the form $w^{t+1} = (1-\gamma) w^{t} + \frac{\gamma}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} y_n$.

In the case $\gamma \in ]0,1]$ this sequence clearly converges using the fact that it is a convex combination of points and that therefore we get a monotone and bounded sequence.

What happens if $\gamma \ni ]0,1]$?

Comment: If you define $c=\frac{\gamma}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Ny_n$ then your recursion is $w[t+1] = (1-\gamma)w[t] + c$ and this is a linear recurrence relation over $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ that can be solved for any $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.  Do you know how to solve those?  For example, find a particular solutoin, and a class of homogeneous solutions?

Comment: @Michael you're right using characteristic polynomial isn't it?

Comment: I suppose so. You can look for homogeneous solutions of the type $w[t] = x^t$.  And particular solutions of the type $w[t]=b$ (constant).

Comment: up to now my conclusion is that it only converges if  $ 0 < \gamma \le 2$

Comment: For $\gamma=2$ it does not necessarily converge.